# Unique-like constraint in a complex scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table in SQL Server 2016, as shown below. Records are inserted into the table each quarter, for all partners.

Constraint Needed: Should allow only one BatchID for a partnerID for a year-quarter, for a Distribution_Type. However it is allowed to have multiple records with same BatchID for the partner for a given year-quarter, for a distribution type.

How to create such a constraint in the table? If it can be done without trigger that would be great.

[image]

Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Distribution]
(
    [Distribtution_Result_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PartnerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Distribution_Year] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Distribution_Quarter] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Distribution_Amount] [decimal](16, 4) NULL,
    [Distribution_Type] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Batch_ID] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Yes, this can be solved if you add a second table and an FK from this to the second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9)'s comment:

> Yes, this can be solved if you add a second table and an FK from this to the second table

If the requirement is one `BatchId` per `PartnerId`,`Year`,`Quarter`,`Distribution_Type` then you will need a table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Partner_Batch --Or whatever
(
    PartnerID             INT           NOT NULL,
    Distribution_Year     INT           NOT NULL,
    Distribution_Quarter  INT           NOT NULL,
    Distribution_Type     VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,
    Batch_ID              INT           NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Partner_Batch PRIMARY KEY (PartnerId, Distribution_Year, Distribution_Quarter, Distribution_Type)
)
```

Of course you'd need the relevant FK references for `PartnerID` and `Batch_ID` as well as something to ensure Quarter is only valid values (1,2,3,4).

You would then modify your existing table with the foreign key constraint to ensure the rule is enforced:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Distribution]
(
    Distribtution_Result_ID   INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    PartnerID                 INT               NOT NULL,
    Distribution_Year         INT               NOT NULL,
    Distribution_Quarter      INT               NOT NULL,
    Distribution_Amount       DECIMAL(16,4)     NULL,
    Distribution_Type         VARCHAR(100)      NOT NULL, --Note: This column cannot be NULL
    Batch_ID                  INT               NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Distribution_Partner_Batch FOREIGN KEY (PartnerId, Distribution_Year, Distribution_Quarter, Distribution_Type) REFERENCES dbo.Partner_Batch (PartnerId, Distribution_Year, Distribution_Quarter, Distribution_Type) --I would use a more descriptive name for the relation, but I don't have enough information about your system
)
```

From afar, there's a lot more work to be done, but at minimum I'd say you'd need to:

1. Have a reference table for `Distribution_Type` to only allow valid values.
2. Trim down the data type for `Distribution_Type` or substitute a shortname/code.
3. Define an actual key for `Distribution` other than the row identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a check constraint on your table.
If the logic required is complexe, you could use a fonction to achieve your goal.

Here's another post with a good example.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999707/complex-check-constraint

Comment: not a very good idea

Comment: @ypercube, could you please explain why this is not a good idea ? Are you concern about performance impact ? Are you saying it won't work ? Please give more details so that we can learn from it.